# Make API call each time a different option is selected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv5vl50j1w) running.

When the user selects a currency, it should run the `getHistory()` function, and update the state with the new history. which should then be reflected in the `Graph` component.

This is not happening. It just renders the previous dataset and the API call complains 
`Failed to get history Error: Request failed with status code 404`

Comment: Why did you change the original code? I was very close on getting the solution but now it's a completely different source, and the old code is now giving some ridicules `Could not find module in path: './Graph'` error.

Comment: I'm so sorry pal. I was putting the api call into the Graph class. the original version is here. https://github.com/cloggy45/CoinDash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by moving the API call to the associated component container and using the life cycle method `componentDidMount`.